# How can I execute this cURL command with AJAX?

Tags: jquery, ajax, google-chrome, curl, ssl-certificate

I've searched up and down and have tried a variety of different AJAX implementations to try and figure out how to go about doing this.

I have a pretty simple cURL command, that should login and authenticate with the API:

`curl -c cjar -b cjar -k -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST https://bmc/login -d "{\"data\": [ \"username\", \"password\" ] }"`

How am I supposed to write this in AJAX? :[

One issue: `Failed to load resource: net::ERR_INSECURE_RESPONSE`

The request is currently stalled... so any idea on how to go about writing this via AJAX would be extremely helpful.

Edit: Just wanted to make a note that I am particularly unsure of how to handle `-c cjar -b cjar` and especially `-k`

Edit: The `net::ERR_INSECURE_RESPONSE` has to do with a self-signed certificate issue, at least I'm pretty sure that's the problem. I've added custom "trust" settings to the localhost certificate, but I'm still have issues.

[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`cURL` is able to send and receive data cross domain to remote servers but that is not the case with `javascript` (for security reasons).

I would suggest writing a `server-side proxy` that gathers the information you need then displays it in a way that you can use `AJAX` to then get from the page.

A [curl example](http://php.net/manual/en/curl.examples.php) in PHP:

```
<?php
        // create curl resource
        $ch = curl_init();

        // set url
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "example.com");

        //return the transfer as a string
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

        // $output contains the output string
        $output = curl_exec($ch);

        // close curl resource to free up system resources
        curl_close($ch);     
?>
```

Comment: Thank you! And this may very well have to be the fallback. So just for confirmation, there's no possible way to do this via client-side only?

Comment: Nope. Besides, if you did it all client side, you could have XSS security vulnerabilities and anyone could steal your code and use it.

Comment: Great! :) At least I know where to go from here! :D Thank you.

Comment: No problem! Glad i could help.